# Kohana 3.3 ORM - Database Views

Tags: kohana, kohana-3

Is there a way to use the orm factory to pull from a view instead of a table?  I was hoping that the syntax would be equivalent to pulling from a table:

```
$buyers = ORM::factory('vbuyer'); //where vbuyers is the name of the view
```

This results in the error : `ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Class 'Model_Vbuyer' not found`

Unfortunately that doesn't seem to work.  Can I have the orm map a view to a model, or do I have to use the `DB::select('*')->from('vbuyers')` approach?

EDIT: The problem was actually that the filename of the vbuyer model was incorrect, it had an underscore v_buyer.  Removed the underscore and it worked.

EDIT: To answer the original question - yes, you can use the ORM factory to generate models based on database views.  The problem in this case was unrelated, see above.

Comment: "that doesn't seem to work" --- doesn't work isn't a proper issue explanation

Comment: @zerkms - updated the question with the error message thrown

Comment: Have you created the model class?

Comment: @zerkms - I did create the model class - I had previously had an underscore in the name of the view, and it didn't work.  So thinking that the underscore was the problem i took it out from the view and model name, but forgot to take the underscore out of the model's filename.  Are underscores not allowed in model names?  Btw, it's working now that i renamed the file!

Comment: the filename should be `classes/model/vbuyer.php`

Comment: @zerkms - yup - that's what it is now.  Well it works, thanks!

Comment: so no one `answered` the question?

Comment: @ThorpeObazee - the answer to the original question was answered by fixing the problem, I have updated the question to state that.  But no there have not been any "answers" for this since it's no longer a question really. I have voted to close this myself.  I'm unaware though of any other documentation that explains you can use the ORM to generate a model from a databse view, so maybe it's good to keep this around for that purpose